# No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.Class] found for dependency [java.lang.Class<org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<?, ?>>]

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, spring-data-cassandra

I have started working with Spring framework. Here I am working with Spring Data - Cassandra Repository modular application. I could able to test a spring-data-cassandra application individually, whereas when I try to use as a moudle in a project and scan the packages of components from other module like...

```
<context:component-scan base-package="example.dao,example.domain" />
```

I am getting an error

> No qualifying bean of type [example.domain.EventRepository] found for dependency [example.domain.EventRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

I can share you the code, if required.

The way I have done for another modules works fine.

I am not getting where is the problem.

Please find the code below for DAO CLASS.

```
@Service 
@Transactional
public class EventDao {

@Autowired
private EventRepository eventRepository;

/*public EventDao(EventRepository eventRepository) {

    this.eventRepository = eventRepository;
}*/

private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventDao.class);

public Event saveMember(Event member) {
    eventRepository.save(member);

    return member;
}
}
```

My Repository interface.

```
package example.domain;

import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.CassandraRepository;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.Query;

public interface EventRepository extends CassandraRepository<Event> {

@Query("select * from event where type = ?0 and bucket=?1")
Iterable<Event> findByTypeAndBucket(String type, String bucket);
}
```

My Cassandra configuration class.

```
package example;


@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:cassandra.properties" })
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = { "example" })
 public class CassandraConfiguration extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CassandraConfiguration.class);

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
    CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
    cluster.setContactPoints(environment.getProperty("cassandra.contactpoints"));
    cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("cassandra.port")));
    return cluster;
}

@Override
protected String getKeyspaceName() {
    return environment.getProperty("cassandra.keyspace");
}

@Bean
public CassandraMappingContext cassandraMapping() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

I could able to create individual spring-data-cassandra and spring-data-neo4j modules seperately with other service modules and its working fine in both the modules.
But I have another module with Neo4j spring-data-neo4j module in the same project, when I try to run both(neo4j+cassandra) the modules under the same project its creating the problem.

still waiting for the help! I have tried my best! 
Thanks!

Comment: Did you annotate Your EventRepository as e.g. `@Repository`, `@Component` etc.?

Comment: Please share more details. There are many possible causes: what kind of modules are we talking about? maven jars (should work)? maven wars (don't)? OSGI (I expect problems)? How are your application contexts structured?

Comment: These might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170404/how-to-autowire-class-in-maven-multi-module-spring-web-app http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106094/right-way-to-use-componentscan-in-multi-module-java-config-spring-mvc-app

Comment: @JensSchauder! from module maven war, my controller calls Dao which is of module maven jar

Comment: @UweAllner! My Class and interface looks like above.

Comment: Do you have `@EnableCassandraRepositories` or `<cassandra:repositories/>` configured?

Comment: How does your configuration look like and in which module is it?

Comment: the above configuration class is in Cassandra Moudle

Comment: so is the cassandra module the jar module, the war module or something else?

Comment: it is a jar module

Comment: Problem got rectified for cassandra, but when I integrate with Neo4j its creating the following problem